# Visual Studio 2010 and boost::bind

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, boost

I have this simple piece of code that uses boost::bind:

```
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> a;
    std::vector<std::pair<bool,int> > b;

    a.push_back(1);
    a.push_back(2);
    a.push_back(3);

    std::transform(a.begin(), a.end(), std::back_inserter(b),
                   boost::bind(std::make_pair<bool, int>, false, _1));
}
```

I'm getting a ton of errors in VS2010 RC, such as:

```
Error   1   error C2780: 'boost::_bi::bind_t<_bi::dm_result<MT::* ,A1>::type,boost::_mfi::dm<M,T>,_bi::list_av_1<A1>::type> boost::bind(M T::* ,A1)' : expects 2 arguments - 3 provided c:\projects\testtuple\main.cpp  18  
Error   2   error C2780: 'boost::_bi::bind_t<Rt2,boost::_mfi::cmf8<R,T,B1,B2,B3,B4,B5,B6,B7,B8>,_bi::list_av_9<A1,A2,A3,A4,A5,A6,A7,A8,A9>::type> boost::bind(boost::type<T>,R (__thiscall T::* )(B1,B2,B3,B4,B5,B6,B7,B8) const,A1,A2,A3,A4,A5,A6,A7,A8,A9)' : expects 11 arguments - 3 provided   c:\projects\testtuple\main.cpp  18
```

Am I doing something wrong? If this is a bug in the compiler, how can I workaround it?

EDIT: added the entire test case.

**Clarification: the code compiles in VS2008.**

Comment: Maybe you have a conflict between `std::tr1::bind` and `boost::bind` but it's hard to tell if you don't post a full example

Comment: Also why do you suggest that the problem is caused by a bug in VC++ 2010, have you tried to compile this code on a different compiler?

Comment: see my edit for the full code. it compiles fine in VS2008.

Comment: it's true, it also compiles in GCC. See my anwer for a possible workaround.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update:**

The problem is that `make_pair` seems to be overloaded in the STL that ships with VS2010 (it wasn't in previous versions of VS or in GCC). The workaround is to make explicit which of the overloads you want, with a cast:

```
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>


int main()
{
    std::vector<int> a;
    std::vector<std::pair<bool,int> > b;

    a.push_back(1);
    a.push_back(2);
    a.push_back(3);

    typedef std::pair<bool, int> (*MakePairType)(bool, int);

    std::transform(a.begin(), a.end(), std::back_inserter(b),
                    boost::bind((MakePairType)&std::make_pair<bool, int>,
                                false, _1));
}
```

For additional details see the [Boost bind manual](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/bind/bind.html#Troubleshooting).

Comment: No, still plenty of errors, now they're just coming from `std::bind`.   
`Error 1 error C2780: 'std::tr1::_Bind<_Ret,_Ret,std::tr1::_Bind0<std::tr1::_Callable_obj<_Fty>>> std::tr1::bind(_Fty)' : expects 1 arguments - 3 provided c:\projects\testtuple\main.cpp 17`

Comment: Maybe it's because `make_pair` is overloaded, can you try with a dummy `std::pair<bool, int> foo(bool,int)` function of your own instead of `make_pair`?

Comment: it worked with a dummy function. but I have so many places using `std::make_pair`, I can't create a dummy function everywhere, do you have a suggestion?

Comment: Check the section "Binding an overloaded function" here: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/bind/bind.html#Troubleshooting

Comment: `std::make_pair<bool, int>` is not overloaded.

Comment: actually it is in VS2010. one version accepts a const reference and the other an r-value reference. I got it to work if I followed how to bind an overloaded function at `bind` docs. if you edit your answer to include it and mention that it's a workaround I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just want <strike>std::bind1st(&std::make_pair, false)</strike>
`std::bind1st(std::ptr_fun(&std::make_pair<bool, int>), false))`

Comment: How would the new `transform` look? I tried `std::transform(a.begin(), a.end(), std::back_inserter(b), std::bind1st(&std::make_pair<bool, int>, false));` but it doesn't compile. Also what if I want to bind both of `make_pair` parameters?

Comment: I got it to work if I wrapped `make_pair` with `std::ptr_fun`

Comment: You might need `std::bind1st(std::ptr_fun(&std::make_pair<bool, int>), false))`. bind1st only binds function objects.

Comment: Can I use `bind1st` to bind both parameters? Suppose I have a `pair<int, int>` and I want both parameters to `make_pair` to get bound. Something similar to `boost::bind(std::make_pair<int, int>, _1, _1)`

Comment: Sorry - fixed. And no, I suggested `bind1st` precisely because your original problem was simple. `boost::bind` is far more powerful.