# Using std::tr1::bind with std::vector::push_back

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, bind

Why my VS2010 can't compile this code:

```
#include <functional>
#include <vector>
int main()
{
    std::vector<int> vec;
    std::bind(&std::vector<int>::push_back, std::ref(vec), 1)();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please paste-in the error you're getting. Even if we are willing to help, we are not psychics.

Comment: I see no error in this. I run that code and it works well. Be sure to include tr1/functional.

Comment: It doesn't compile in VS2010, no <tr1/functional> header, just <functional>. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: VS2010 already provides the c++0x functionality. Thus in order to use `std::bind` just include `<functional>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
struct push_back {
    void
    operator()(std::vector<int>& vector, int i) const
    {
        vector.push_back(i);
    }
};

// somewhere else:
std::vector<int> vec;
std::tr1::bind(push_back(), std::tr1::ref(vec), 1)();
```

With C++03 note that `push_back` cannot be a local type; with C++11 it can but it would be more idiomatic (and completely equivalent) to use a lambda.

In all likeliness your implementation provides overloads for `std::vector<T>::push_back` and thus its address would have to be disambiguated. If this is what happened, your compiler should have provided you with an appropriate error message. In *all* cases, you should explain what you mean by "it's not possible".

---

> The point is not to use such helper
>   functions. – magenta

Then why didn't you put it in the question? I can't read your mind.

You can also try this:

```
std::vector<int> vec;
void (std::vector<int>::*push_back)(int const&) = &std::vector<int>::push_back;
std::tr1::bind(push_back(), std::tr1::ref(vec), 1)();
```

Which I believe is not guaranteed to success.

Comment: @magenta Please amend your question then

Answer (score 5):

You should be more specific why this doesn't seem to work for you.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tr1/functional>
#include <vector>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    std::vector<int> vec;
    std::tr1::bind(&std::vector<int>::push_back, std::tr1::ref(vec), 1)();
    std::cout << "vec.size = " << vec.size() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "vec[0] = " << vec[0] << std::endl;
    return 0;
}

$ gcc -o test -lstdc++ test.cpp && ./test
vec.size = 1
vec[0] = 1
```

**Update:** Luc Danton is right, the issue here is the overloaded `push_back`.  See question [Are there boost::bind issues with VS2010 ?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4248357/49604).  Also, note that the issue is not limited to `push_back`, see [Visual Studio 2010 and boost::bind](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2295969/49604).

Comment: It just doesn't compile. And the problem seems to be in #include <tr1/functional>. I'm using VS2010 and there is no such a header.

Comment: @magenta: VS2010 just doesn't have the tr1 headers, they're embedded in the non-tr1 ones. Also, VS2010 imports all important tr1 names in the normal std namespace, so just include `<functional>` and use `std::bind`, without the `tr1`.

Answer (score 4):

The bottom line is that what you're trying to do isn't possible in *portable* C++. `std::vector<>::push_back` is guaranteed to be overloaded in C++11 compilers, as at a minimum there must be an overload for lvalues and an overload for rvalues.

*Usually*, when taking the address of an overloaded member function, §13.4/1 in the C++11 FDIS tells us that we can control which overload we're taking the address of thusly:

> A use of an overloaded function name without arguments is resolved in certain contexts to a function, a pointer to function or a pointer to member function for a specific function from the overload set. A function template name is considered to name a set of overloaded functions in such contexts. **The function selected is the one whose type is identical to the function type of the target type required in the context.** [ *Note:* That is, the class of which the function is a member is ignored when matching a pointer-to-member-function type. *—end note* ] The target can be
>
> - an object or reference being initialized,
> - the left side of an assignment,
> - a parameter of a function,
> - a parameter of a user-defined operator,
> - the return value of a function, operator function, or conversion,
> - **an explicit type conversion**, or
> - a non-type template-parameter.
>
> The overloaded function name can be preceded by the `&` operator. An overloaded function name shall not be used without arguments in contexts other than those listed. [ *Note:* Any redundant set of parentheses surrounding the overloaded function name is ignored. *—end note* ]

*The problem* comes from §17.6.5.5/2:

> An implementation may declare additional non-virtual member function signatures within a class by adding arguments with default values to a member function signature; **hence, the address of a member function of a class in the C++ standard library has an unspecified type.**

Consequently, it is not portable to ever take the address of a standard library class member function, as the type of such an expression is by definition unknowable except on an implementation-by-implementation basis.

Luc Danton's proposed workaround (specifically, using a lambda) is also what I would recommend:

```
std::vector<int> vec;
[&](){ vec.push_back(1); }();
```

Comment: Yes, lambda is the probably the best choice here if we use C++0x. But actually I was just curious why VS2010 wasn't able to compile my code.

Answer (score 0):

It should propably lok like this:

```
std::vector<int> vec;
std::tr1::bind(&std::vector<int>::push_back, std::tr1::ref(vec), _1)(1);
```