# std::foreach with boost::bind

Tags: c++, stl, boost-bind

What's wrong with this:

```
template <typename T>
std::list<T> & operator+=(std::list<T> & first, std::list<T> const& second)
{
    std::for_each(second.begin(), second.end(), boost::bind(&std::list<T>::push_back, first, _1));

    return first;
}
```

It compiles fine, but doesn't work.

Comment: what does "doesn't work" mean exactly?

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but if your code is really this contrived (as opposed to the example being stripped-down for the question, I mean), what's wrong with `std::copy` with a `std::back_inserter`?

Comment: To complement Tomalak, the standard idiom of doing this thing in c++ is: `std::copy(second.begin(), second.end(), std::back_inserter(first));`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use `boost::ref` to pass an argument/object via reference, otherwise bind creates an internal copy.

```
std::for_each(
    second.begin(), second.end(),
    boost::bind(&std::list<T>::push_back, boost::ref(first), _1)
);
```

Comment: Of course this doesn't change the fact that `&std::list<T>::push_back` has unspecified behavior so this still may or may not compile (and in fact is guaranteed **not** to on any compiler with rvalue reference support)...

Comment: Thanks Cat, this works.
@ildjarn, could you link to more information about why &std::list<T>::push_back would have unspecified behavior?

Comment: @Heptic : [Using std::tr1::bind with std::vector::push_back](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6007563/using-stdtr1bind-with-stdvectorpush-back/6008660#6008660)

Comment: @Heptic: Still, the best way to do what you want to do is back_inserter, treat this answer more as a generic solution to "why my bind operates on a different object than it should even though I have references".

Answer (score 6):

Note that while Cat Plus Plus's solution would work for you, the encouraged way to do such things in C++03 (before the advent if lambdas in the upcoming standard version) is to use the standard library algorithms and functors. Unfortunately, in some cases they get quite convoluted themselves, but in this case I think they produce clearer code:

```
std::copy(second.begin(), second.end(), std::back_inserter(first));
```

Comment: "*Note that while Cat Plus Plus's solution would work for you*" Absolutely not; that code would refuse to compile on any compiler released in the last year or two.

Comment: @BoazYaniv : Until he upgrades his compiler. ;-]

Comment: #including algorithm and iterator and then using `std::copy()` and `back_inserter()` here is too much work for no reason, imo. And really, when the standard offers a member function you should use that rather than a generic algorithm.

Comment: @wilhelmtell : While I agree that `list<>::insert` is more appropriate here, what real C++ code doesn't have `algorithm` and `iterator` included already?

Comment: @wilhelmtell: in this case of a list<T>, I'll concede that using insert() is even more readable, but `std::copy` is useful in many cases where you don't want to get fixed on a single container.

Answer (score 3):

```
std::list<T> ls;
std::list<T> ls0;
// ...
ls.insert(ls.end(), ls0.begin(), ls0.end());
```